# Remove unique permission on list item

Tags: sharepoint-online, csom

I have run the csom code for break inheritance and set the unique permission on list item (ex.contribute). when user modified the list item, i want to the remove that unique permission and set other permission (ex.read).

```
  if (listItem.HasUniqueRoleAssignments)
   {
     listItem.BreakRoleInheritance(false, false);
     //istItem.ResetRoleInheritance();    
     context.ExecuteQuery();
    }

 if (!listItem.HasUniqueRoleAssignments)
   {
    listItem.BreakRoleInheritance(false, false);
    context.ExecuteQuery();
    }
 Console.WriteLine("BreakRoleInheritance");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the below code to remove the unqiue permission, then set the unique permission on list item to read.

```
  ClientContext ctx = new ClientContext("https://yoursite/sites/dev");
  Web web = ctx.Web;
  List list = web.Lists.GetByTitle("test");
  ListItem listitem = list.GetItemById("1");
  listitem.ResetRoleInheritance();
  listitem.BreakRoleInheritance(false,false);
  User user = web.SiteUsers.GetByLoginName(@"contoso\michael");
  RoleDefinitionBindingCollection roleDefinitionBinding = new RoleDefinitionBindingCollection(ctx);
  roleDefinitionBinding.Add(web.RoleDefinitions.GetByType(RoleType.Reader));
  listitem.RoleAssignments.Add(user, roleDefinitionBinding);
  ctx.ExecuteQuery();
```

Comment: You saved my day. It is working fine. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to use Microsoft Power Automate which will be easy for breaking inheritance and setting unique permission on item.